# inserting to a sql table using java setText() method values

Tags: java, sql

```
   String sql="Insert into daily_ot (date,empNo,ot1hrs,ot2hrs,ot1amt,ot2amt) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
         try{
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, ((JTextField) date.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            pst.setString(2,com_emp.getSelectedItem().toString());
            pst.setString(3, txt_ot1.getText());
            pst.setString(4,  txt_ott2.getText());
            pst.setString(5, txt_ot1_amt.getText());
            pst.setString(6, txt_ot2_amt.getText());                       
             pst.execute();

 }catch(Exception e){

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

 } 
  finally{
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }
             catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
```

I used this java code to insert into the daily_ot table in sqliteManager. Here the values are not keyboard inserted. The values are taken as the setText() method values set in previous methods. But the setText() method values can't be inserted into the table. but when inserted using keyboard it works.I want to use setText() method values to insert into the table.Could someone please help in this ?

Here I use one button for selection query and the other button for the insert query? Is this the reason why the insertion code doesn't work when use the button with selection query?

Comment: "Doesnt work" isnt a problem description that would work for us:

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: If you used the **setText()** method within other methods to fill your JTextFields (or whatever) then you really shouldn't have any problem using the code you already have.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/4725875/devilshnd.....the jtable refreshes,but the sql table doesn't

Comment: use `pst.executeUpdate();`

Comment: @ https://stackoverflow.com/users/3992939/c0der I tried pst.executeUpdate(); . It also doesn't help in adding data to sql table

Comment: Could someone please give the reason why this isn't working properly?

Comment: `Could someone please give the reason why this isn't working properly? –` - how do you expect us to do that? There is no reason using someCoponent.setText(...) and someComponent.getText() should not work. There is no difference between using setText() or typing text into the text field. So you need to add a `System.out.println( txt_ot1 );` statement into your code to see what value is returned. If it is not the value you expect, then it means your code that invokes the setText() statement is not being executed. So YOU need to debug your own code.